# handling with multiple mat-errors

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formbuilder

I have my error handling for mat-input like this

```
      <mat-form-field>
        <input formControlName="title" matInput placeholder="Title*" />
        <mat-error *ngIf="addNewForm.get('title').errors?.required">
          Can not be empty
        </mat-error>
        <mat-error *ngIf="addNewForm.get('title').errors?.minlength">
          Min length is 1 character
        </mat-error>
        <mat-error *ngIf="addNewForm.get('title').errors?.maxlength">
          Max length is 255 characters
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field>
        <input formControlName="name" matInput placeholder="Name*" />
        <mat-error *ngIf="addNewForm.get('name').errors?.required">
          Can not be empty
        </mat-error>
        <mat-error *ngIf="addNewForm.get('name').errors?.minlength">
          Min length is 1 character
        </mat-error>
        <mat-error *ngIf="addNewForm.get('name').errors?.maxlength">
          Max length is 255 characters
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
```

How to handle this directly in component, soo instead of writing all of this errors manually, 
check all in component and dynamically set errors, something like this

```
      <mat-form-field>
        <input formControlName="title" matInput placeholder="Title*" />
        <mat-error>{{ someError }}</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field>
        <input formControlName="name" matInput placeholder="Name*" />
        <mat-error>{{ someError }}</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
```

Here is component

```
this.addNewUserForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      title: [
        "",
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(1),
          Validators.maxLength(255),
          noWhitespaceValidator
        ]
      ],
      name: [
        "",
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(4),
          Validators.maxLength(255),
          noWhitespaceValidator
        ]
      ]
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a getter function which returns simply the error message. Like this:

```
get errorMessage(): string {
   const form: FormControl = (this.addNewUserForm.get('title') as FormControl);
   return form.hasError('required') ?
     'Required error message' :
     form.hasError('maxlength') ?
     'Max length error' : 
     form.hasError('minlength') ?
     'Min length error' :
     form.hasError('nowhitespaceerror') ?
     'No white space error' : '';
}
```

After this you simply use this method like a variable in template:

```
<mat-error>{{ errorMessage }}</mat-error>
```

Or a simple solution based on this example: [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a8t9ki?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-error-state-matcher-example.html).

```js
export class InputErrorExample {
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  errorMessages = {
    maxlength: 'max',
    minlength: 'min',
    email: 'email'
  };

  addNewUserForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      title: [
        "",
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(1),
          Validators.maxLength(255),
          Validators.email
          // noWhitespaceValidator
        ]
      ]
    });

  errors(ctrl: FormControl): string[] {
    return ctrl.errors ? Object.keys(ctrl.errors) : [];
  }
}
```

```html
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Email" [formControl]="addNewUserForm.get('title')"
           [errorStateMatcher]="matcher">
    <mat-hint>Errors appear instantly!</mat-hint>
    <mat-error>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let error of errors(addNewUserForm.get('title'))">
        {{ errorMessages[error] }} <br>
      </ng-container>
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Comment: I set here in the example only one input item, but I have multiple of them, haw to handle this with multiple? Thnx

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a8t9ki?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-error-state-matcher-example.html try this, i think is a simple and good solution for your use case.

Comment: And with this solution you can see all active errors, and you can easily reuse this.

Comment: cool man... so for every input I need to add `<ng-container *ngFor="let error of errors(addNewUserForm.get('title'))">
        {{ errorMessages[error] }} <br>
      </ng-container>` if I understand you correctly?

Comment: Sure, and just add all the different erro types to the `errorMessages` object, and change the parameter `formControl` in the `*ngFor` and thats it. (See the ts file in my example).

Comment: thnx... but where to put custom messages like `Min length is 1 character` etc.... sry... I found it... I didn't see it

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:

Listen to the `statusChanges` observable of your `FormControl` instance and when it emits, get its first error.

```js
const titleCtrl = this.addNewUserForm.get('title');

const titleErr$ = titleCtrl.statusChanges
  .pipe(
   filter(status => status === 'INVALID'),
   map(() => {
    if (!titleCtrl.errors) {
      return null; 
    }   

    // Returning the first error
    for (const errName in titleCtrl.errors) {
       return titleCtrl.errors[errName];
     }
   }),
   filter(err => !!err)
  )
```

Now, it depends on your use-case.

If you need to use your error only once in the template, you can use the **async pipe**.

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <input formControlName="title" matInput placeholder="Title*" />
    <mat-error>{{ titleErr$ | async }}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

If you need to use the error in multiple places or if you need to perform the same logic for multiple `FormControl`s, you can either subscribe in the component(**imperative** way) or you can find a way to **combine** all the errors and keep the subscription in the view(**reactive** way).

Bear in mind that if you subscribe in the component class, you'll have to unsubscribe.

Comment: Thnx, I have multiple input fields, here in example I put only one... how to handle this?